# Accessing MLFlow UI with a folder name different than mlruns

Tags: mlflow

I set the `tracking_uri` to a folder name different than `mlruns`.

Is there a way I can open the **MLFlow UI** pointing to the new folder name for mlruns?

I know I can rename the folder back to `mlruns`, which gets me access to all of my metrics and parameters for each experiment, but the artifacts are not accessible, since they were logged to a different folder name than mlruns.

Comment: Can you share some more information here, some screenshots of what you are seeing would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the UI and specify the folder location with the `--backend-store-uri` and `--default-artifact-root` CLI options. In your case you would use the `file://` scheme.

See the docs for more information:
https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-ui

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code example ? Cheers